# datatable desalinea thead de tbody al agregarle scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

estoy implementando una databable con jquery. Le necesito agregar un alto, pero la tabla tiene muchos registros, por lo que tambien debo agregarle un scroll, pero al hacer esto, el theader de la tabla se desacopla del body de la tabla quedando de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo volver a hacer que se vuelva a alinear el thead con el tbody de mi datatable pero manteniendo el scroll???

El código de mi datatable es el siguiente, de antemano muchas gracias!!

```
            $('#table-preview-employees').dataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "searching": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": true,
                "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página",
                    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron registros",
                    "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                    "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
                    "search": "Buscar:",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first": "Primero",
                        "last": "Último",
                        "next": "Siguiente",
                        "previous": "Anterior"
                    },
                },
                // max height and scroll if table is too big
                "scrollY": "300px",
                "scrollCollapse": false,

            });
```

Comment: ¿Eso te pasa al cargar la página o como respuesta a un evento como redimensionar u otro?  Si es en un evento intenta usar esto: `$('#table-preview-employees').dataTable( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();` a ver si cuela (encontrado [en este enlace](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41587/scrolly-misaligned-table-headers-with-bootstrap#Comment_108414))